# Gradle continuous build (+ ktor auto-reload) does not detect changes when running inside of a container

Tags: docker, kotlin, gradle, docker-compose, ktor

I'm developing an API web-server using Ktor and I want to containerize the project and run it using Docker. I have made this work using the following Dockerfile & docker-compose.yml files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-17-jdk bash && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /backend

CMD ["./gradlew", "run"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version:  "3.8"

services:
  ktor-backend:
    build: ./
    container_name: company-backend
    volumes:
      - ./:/backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      - url=${pg_url}
      - username=${pg_username}
      - password=${pg_password}
```

Then I simply run `docker-compose up --build` and access the api normally through `localhost:8080` on the host Windows machine.

This displays:

```
[main] DEBUG Application - Watching /backend/build/classes/kotlin/main for changes.
[main] DEBUG Application - Watching /backend/build/resources/main for changes.
[main] DEBUG Application - Watching /backend/build/classes/kotlin/main/app for changes.
[main] DEBUG Application - Watching /backend/build/classes/kotlin/main/app/joblink/plugins for changes.
[main] DEBUG Application - Watching /backend/build/classes/kotlin/main/app/joblink for changes.
[main] DEBUG Application - Watching /backend/build/classes/kotlin/main/META-INF for changes.
```

Once that's done, I open a second terminal and execute `docker exec -t -i joblink-backend bash` to access the command-line and lastly execute `./gradlew -t installDist` to set up continuous build. Now, once this succeeds, gradle prints `Waiting for changes to input files... (ctrl-d to exit)` as you would expect.

Once I edit the Routing.kt file though in my source code, the change does not seem to trigger a rebuild. I checked the Routing.kt file's contents in the docker container's volume, and it seems to be successfully synced. Same seems to apply to the `build/classes/.../plugins/` respective .class files.

The application's HOCON file is defined as:

```
ktor {
    development = true
    deployment {
        port = 8080
        port = ${?PORT}
        autoreload = true
    }
    application {
        modules = [ app.joblink.ApplicationKt.module ]
    }
}
```

and in my Application.kt file:

```
fun Application.module() {
    configureSecurity()
    configureHTTP()
    configureSerialization()
    configureDatabases()
    configureRouting()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(
        Netty,
        watchPaths = listOf("backend","classes"),
        module = Application::module
    ).start(true)
    println("test")
}
```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Does this work with a plain JVM?  What benefits are you getting by introducing Docker into this workflow?

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to directly test things in an environment that simulates where the web-server will be actually running (on a linux-based cloud server, inside of a docker container along with a database container). Is my approach not common?

Comment: You can do integration testing with the same image you'd run in production; in a JVM language that typically only includes the jar file and none of the sources.  Doing live development, in an isolated container, on a remote system, is complex and hard to manage, and Docker makes it harder.  You should have a good suite of unit tests with minimal-to-no external dependencies that you can run on your local system, without the cloud environment or database or Docker.

Comment: What is your host OS?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Windows 11

Comment: For the sake of testing, can you check the auto-reloading on a Linux or Mac host?